# Virtuall Manager : CentOS Guest Install Garbled Text

Tags: centos, debian, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I'm trying to install CentOS 6.5 with virtual manager but the menu is garbled. Host machine is running on Debian Wheezy. Thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: How did you configure the VM, especially the video settings?

Comment: The guest settings? It's cirrus.

Comment: Well, yes, that would cause the problem. Why didn't you choose qxl/spice?

Comment: It didn't make any differences. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It makes no difference on whether the its CentOS or debian, there still seems to be issues with CentOS guest.